# How can you update “Incredible PBX” for the Raspberry Pi without using the non-free, $20/year updater?

Tags: linux, update

I have been a fan of Asterisk, and in particular the project The Incredible PBX.

However, they charge $20 per year to update (for the raspberry pi). This updater installs security updates, among other things. They explain that the alternative is to backup the entire server and install a fresh copy with the newest updates (follow by restoring the settings) if you want to avoid using their paid updater.

Is there another way to update The Incredible PBX without using their paid utility? Is it a simple method of apt-get upgrade or something similar? I'm all for a free solution, and I'd rather go to a different distribution than pay an annual fee for updates. Has anyone made a fork for this purpose (kind of like how CentOS is to Redhat)?

Answer (score 5):

The automatic update facility in Incredible PBX is free. We encourage an annual contribution of $20 to help fund the project, but that is entirely up to each user. The updates won't stop coming whether you contribute or not!

Answer (score 4):

As it stands, the system will provide you with 10 free updates, and allows you to disable the update mechanism (in which case, it's just like any other PIAF installation).

Feel free to try a different distribution, of course.

Comment: I would normally flag your post to be closed and down vote it since it doesn't answer the question at all. The problem is - I feel exactly the same. I know that money is hard to get in some parts of the world and 20$ is really a lot there but I don't think this justifies OP's attitude. I believe he don't really get how free software (as a culture) works. He could do the fork himself if its to expensive but it seams that the only acceptable way for him is to use someones else hard work for free.

Comment: When you say it's just like any other PIAF install, does that mean that the $20/yr updater doesn't hinder the usual linux security updates (ie apt-get upgrade)? I haven't actually tried the install because I was put off by the fact that they would charge for security updates, but if it really is no different than a standard desktop install, then that is certainly fine with me.

Comment: I approved an edit that removes the non-factual parts of this answer.  Inflammatory remarks do not belong on a Stack Exchange site, and discussions about the value of work and moral judgments are not on-topic here.